# Creacion y division de datasets

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataset

Hola estaba realizando un practica en **Python** con **numpy** y me surgio el siguiente problema, tengo la variable `indices_filas` esta al usar `.shape` me debe dar como respuesta `(500,)` todo bien.

Pero entonces tengo que crear tres datasets, por medio del uso de indices de filas del nuevo arreglo `indices_filas` las divisiones son 60/20/20 para train/validation/test, pude completar para cada caso en una línea de código y luego me muestra la plantilla de código :

```
# calcule el total del arreglo indices_filas
n = #aqui va indices_filas (supongo)

# calcule los valores de training set, no hardcoded
entre_begin = # n[:60] 
entre_finish = # n[60:] 

# calcule los valores de validation set, no hardcoded
val_begin = # n[:20]
val_finish = # n[20:]

# calcule los valores del test set, no hardcoded
prueba_begin = # n[:20]
prueba_finish = # n[20:]
```

Más o menos asÍ lo he desarrollado, sin embargo, al imprimir el resultado no muestra el valor esperado que deberian ser:

```
entre_begin = 0  
entre_finish = 300  
val_begin = 300  
val_finish = 400  
prueba_begin = 400  
prueba_finish = 500
```

Mi lógica me indica que deberia ser algo así:

```
entre_begin = n[:60]
entre_finish = (n - entre_begin)[60:] 

val_begin = (n - entre_finish )[:20] 
val_finish = (n - val_begin )[20:] 

prueba_begin = (n - val_finish )[:20] 
prueba_finish = (n - prueba_begin )[20:]
```

Así que estoy algo perdido en esta parte de la práctica. Este problema es mas largo y no puse las otras partes porque supongo que están bien pero si desean puedo agregarlas si hacen falta

Comment: Supongo que esos valores 60/20/20 son porcentajes (ya que al final suman 100). Por tanto el índice particular por el que tienes que partir no es 60, sino el 60% del total de índices. Es decir 0.60*500 = 300. Análogamente 20 sería 0.20*500 = 100

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, solo tienes que hacer los siguientes porcentajes:

- 60% de 500 = 300
- 20% de 500 = 100 (*2 validation y test)

Una vez sabes esto, ya solo tienes que hacer slicing, te pongo un ejemplo explicado:

```
import numpy as np

vector = np.random.rand(500)

#Escogemos del primero al 300
train = vector[:300]
#Escogemos del 300 al 400
validation = vector[300:400]
#Escogemos del 400 hasta el final
test = vector[400:]
```